# Como quito los espacios que pone Android Studio al interpretar Response?

Tags: php, java, android

estoy programando una aplicación en Android Studio que contiene un sistema de registro y LogIn, pero tengo un problema a la hora de comparar el mensaje del servidor php (uso phpmyadmin para la base de datos) con el de el Android Studio, es que este este falla, debido a que el Android Studio interpreta el mensaje como se ve en la imagen. Intente quitar los espacios con "replace" tanto en el Android Studio como en el Php y no funciona.

Alguien sabe como solucionar eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código java:

```
package com.example.gymgame;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    // url maquila xammp

    EditText etUsuario, etContrasena;
    String str_Usuario, str_Contrasena;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        etUsuario = findViewById(R.id.etUsuario);
        etContrasena = findViewById(R.id.etContrasena);


    }




    public void login(View view){
        if(etUsuario.getText().toString().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(etContrasena.getText().toString().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{


            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera...");

            progressDialog.show();
            str_Usuario = etUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
            str_Contrasena= etContrasena.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.1.88:8080/android/login.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("inicio correcto")) {

                        Toast.makeText(login.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(login.this, home.class ));

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(login.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        

                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(login.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("usuario",str_Usuario);
                    params.put("contraseña",str_Contrasena);

                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(login.this);
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    }
    public void btnRegistrar(View view){
        Intent registrar =new Intent(this, registro.class );
        startActivity(registrar);
    }



}
```

código php:

```
<?php
    include "bd.php";

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE user='$usuario' AND pass='$contraseña'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    


    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
        
        echo "inicio correcto"; 
    
    }else{
        echo "no pudo ingresar";
    }
?>
```

nota1: bd.php es la pagina donde tengo la conexión con la base de datos la cual se la asigné a la variable "$conexión".

Comment: Eso, más que un **espacio** parece un ``salto de línea`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no creo que ùnicamente sean los espacios.

Si deseas solo eliminar espacios usa la funciòn `.trim()` :

```
response = response.trim();
```

Pero en este caso el problema son los saltos de linea, asì que puedes usar tambien una expresiòn regular para eliminar los saltos de linea combinando la funciòn .trim() :

```
  response = response.trim().replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
```

de esta forma eliminaras los espacios en los extremos y los saltos de linea.

Comment: Un grande, me funcionó :D

Comment: y si, con espacios me refería al salto de línea, Gracias! :D

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad para solucionar este pequeño inconveniente es usar `.replaceAll`

Puedes probar esto:

```
if(response.contains(" ")){
 response = response.replaceAll(" ", "");
} else if (response.contains("\n")){
 response = response.replaceAll("\n");
}
```